# Split strings (number for unit) when multiple or no delimiters are posibble

Tags: python-3.x

I have a set of data, that look like this:

```
 0.1 - 1000 dB/s
 >45 dB
 30 pm
 +/- 0.3 %
10 - 100                    %
 5 - 20                    mW
 10 - 62                    Watts
 -40 - 85                    C
 0.640 or 0.810 um
  0.640 or 0.810 um
 20
 15
```

First are some numbers, also can contain "+,-", and units. The delimiter between number and unit, can be one or more of space, non breaking space(they can appear also inside between numbers, when are ranges). There are also numbers without unit.

I want to separate, where is the case, the number for the unit. I tried to use `split` by text, works ok for some of them, but not good for others.

Comment: Can you confirm that the data is literally presented as above including leading spaces and gaps between units?

Comment: @blueteeth yes there are gaps, but are not uniform, and also can be gaps after the unit

Comment: What are you trying to get exactly? Then number and the units seperated?

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse, yes I want to separate the numbers, range from unit, where is a unit

Comment: You can use regex to get close, but I'm not good enough with it to handle numbers without units so I would just handle that in the code. [See the regex](https://regex101.com/r/xpjllL/1)

Comment: Your data has no uniformity nor commonality so its incredibally difficult to parse. Can you change the source of the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this regexr I created: https://regexr.com/4t199

It uses named capturing groups for all the different types of line you've given. Then you could check the existence of each part in the dict.

```
import re

p = re.compile('^(\s+)?(?P<sym>([\>\<]|\+\/\-|\-)\s*)?(?P<num>(\d+(\.\d+)?))((?P<orsec> (\-|or) )?(?P<num2>\d+(\.\d+)?)?)?\s*(?P<unit>[a-zA-Z\%\/]+)?$')

text = '''
 0.1 - 1000 dB/s
 >45 dB
 30 pm
 +/- 0.3 %
10 - 100                    %
 5 - 20                    mW
 10 - 62                    Watts
 -40 - 85                    C
 0.640 or 0.810 um
  0.640 or 0.810 um
 20
 15
'''

for line in text.split('\n'):
    if line.strip():
        m = p.match(line)
        if m:
            print(f'{line:40} => {m.groupdict()}')
        else:
            print(f'{line:40} => no match')
```

Which prints something like this:

```
 0.1 - 1000 dB/s                           => {'sym': None, 'num': '0.1', 'orsec': ' - ', 'num2': '1000', 'unit': 'dB/s'}
 >45 dB                                    => {'sym': '>', 'num': '45', 'orsec': None, 'num2': None, 'unit': 'dB'}
 30 pm                                     => {'sym': None, 'num': '30', 'orsec': None, 'num2': None, 'unit': 'pm'}
 +/- 0.3 %                                 => {'sym': '+/- ', 'num': '0.3', 'orsec': None, 'num2': None, 'unit': '%'}
10 - 100                    %              => {'sym': None, 'num': '10', 'orsec': ' - ', 'num2': '100', 'unit': '%'}
 5 - 20                    mW              => {'sym': None, 'num': '5', 'orsec': ' - ', 'num2': '20', 'unit': 'mW'}
 10 - 62                    Watts          => {'sym': None, 'num': '10', 'orsec': ' - ', 'num2': '62', 'unit': 'Watts'}
 -40 - 85                    C             => {'sym': '-', 'num': '40', 'orsec': ' - ', 'num2': '85', 'unit': 'C'}
 0.640 or 0.810 um                         => {'sym': None, 'num': '0.640', 'orsec': ' or ', 'num2': '0.810', 'unit': 'um'}
  0.640 or 0.810 um                        => {'sym': None, 'num': '0.640', 'orsec': ' or ', 'num2': '0.810', 'unit': 'um'}
 20                                        => {'sym': None, 'num': '20', 'orsec': None, 'num2': None, 'unit': None}
 15                                        => {'sym': None, 'num': '15', 'orsec': None, 'num2': None, 'unit': None}
```

You could maybe parse that output for whatever you want to do.

Comment: That regex wants to make me cry but man did you pull everything out. Nice.

Comment: I know. I started writing it out as an explanation, but it became too complicated. Some tidying is required because negative numbers aren't supported, but that can be left as a exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you want to do with the left part but separating the unit from the rest is manageable, but you need to clean up the line.

```
import re
REMOVE_SPACES = re.compile(r'( {2,})') # Matches 2 or more spaces.
lines = []
with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip() # remove leading and trailing spaces
        line = REMOVE_SPACES.sub(' ', line) # Replaces more than one space with a single space
        chunks = line.split(' ') # Split on spaces
        if len(chunks) == 1: # If only one chunk then it has no unit.
            lines.append((chunks[0], None))
        else:
            lines.append((' '.join(chunks[:-1]), chunks[-1])) # Else append the value and the unit
print(*lines, sep='\r\n')
```

Output:

```
('0.1 - 1000', 'dB/s')
('>45', 'dB')
('30', 'pm')
('+/- 0.3', '%')
('10 - 100', '%')
('5 - 20', 'mW')
('10 - 62', 'Watts')
('-40 - 85', 'C')
('0.640 or 0.810', 'um')
('0.640 or 0.810', 'um')
('20', None)
('15', None)
```